# How do I check a user's input as they are entering the input and compare it with values from a databse?

Tags: database, validation, textbox, union, client-side

I have a textbox which takes in user input. I need to compare the input of the user with the value of a union of columns from 4 different tables in a database. The label is supposed to show once the user enters a company name that matches the one stored in the database and warn the user.

```
<tr>
        <td>Company Name:</td>
        <td>
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" Width="200px" OnTextChanged="txtCompanyName_TextChanged" >
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
            <%--to display warning if company name exists--%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfCompanyName" runat="server" 
                ErrorMessage="* Company Name Required"  ValidationGroup="LeadValidation"
                ControlToValidate="txtCompanyName"
                Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyNameExists" Text="Warning: Company Name already Exists" 
                ForeColor="Orange" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Currently I am using the `OnTextChanged` to compare the values but this only validates when a button is pressed.

```
protected void txtCompanyName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCompanyNameExists.Visible = false;
        List<string> CurrentCompNames = new LeadsManager().GetCompanyNames();
        foreach (string companyName in CurrentCompNames)
        {
            if (companyName == txtCompanyName.Text)
            {
                lblCompanyNameExists.Visible = true;
                //return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by setting `AutoPostback="true"` in the `txtCompanyName` textbox.